# What is the peer name If we add two members | amazon managed blockchain | REST Server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, amazon-managed-blockchain

I set up hyperledger fabric network in amazon managed blockchain using [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-network.html). I have used [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/tree/master/ngo-rest-api) as rest server. I have configured peer name as peer1 [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/blob/master/ngo-rest-api/config.json). It was worked properly. Later I added one more member using [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-joint-channel.html). Now member 1 and member 2 should endorse the transaction.

```
docker exec cli peer chaincode instantiate -o $ORDERER \ 
-C ourchannel -n myjointcc -v v0 \
-c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' \
--cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls \
-P "AND ('Member1ID.member','Member2ID.member')"
```

Now I edited [this config file](https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/blob/master/ngo-rest-api/config.json) as `"peers":["peer1", "peer2"]`. But I am getting the following error,

```
[2020-09-02 05:54:20.915] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - Error: Peer with name "peer2" not assigned to this channel
    at Channel._getTargets (/var/www/html/network/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:3515:13)
    at Channel.sendTransactionProposal (/var/www/html/network/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:2791:26)
    at Object.invokeChaincode (/var/www/html/network/app/invoke-transaction.js:41:31)
    at <anonymous>
[2020-09-02 05:54:20.915] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - Failed to invoke chaincode. cause:Error: Peer with name "peer2" not assigned to this channel
```

What should I used instead of peer2? Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Posted a possible cause of your issue, but I faced a different issue following the ngo workshop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127271/unable-to-install-node-packages-for-ngo-blockchain-workshop

Answer (score 0):

you may have missed the step of joinning the peer to the channel:

```
docker exec cli peer channel join -b /opt/home/ourchannel.block \
-o $ORDERER --cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls
```

Both org1 and org2 need to run the following command on their respective Hyperledger Fabric clients to join their peer nodes to the channel